# Some base64 usage in ruby. Is this a good use case?

Tags: ruby, base64

I want to send this data over the wire:

```
payload = {
   sensitive_information:<encrypted_data_with_aes_cipher_and_an_key_and_initialization_vector,
   iv: <some_iv>
}
```

Basically, I want to send a payload with the IV so that the recipient of the data can use the initialization vector.

I need to send this information over http to an api which stores the data. The client will then make a get request to this app to retrieve the payload.

I think using Base64 for this is okay right? I basically just want to encode the information so it doesn't change forms. I want to ensure the client gets this data. Encrypting this `payload` again seems like overkill and plus there's no sensitive information here that I need to encrypt. Encoding will do just fine.

My question is... I don't see the `{` character in base64. This is what I understand the table to be:

[image]

So how is it that I can use Base64 to encode this payload?

I understand how 'food` turns into Base64. But how does '{'?

```
Base64.encode64('food')
=> "Zm9vZA==\n"
[46] pry(Mixer)> Base64.encode64('{')
=> "ew==\n"
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Base64 is simply an **encoding**, not an *encryption*. As such, you shouldn't be using *only* Base64 to transmit sensitive data.

Comment: Base64 encodes bytes to text. `'food'` is converted to bytes with a text encoding (like UTF-8), and then to text with Base64. The `f` in `food` doesn’t correspond with the `f` in that table. If you’re starting out with text, you probably don’t need to encode it at all to send it over HTTP (assuming it’s in a request body and not a querystring). Even if you *aren’t* starting out with text, that works, actually…

Comment: @ObsidianAge I know, the part that is encrypted is in the `sensitive_info` key

Comment: I want to send over a string with these '{' in it.. like json. Can I just send that over http without any changes to the string? What then is Base64 used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re looking at the table backwards. When encoding `'food'`, you’re first converting the text to bytes with some encoding, like UTF-8:

```
'food'.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

'food'.bytes
=> [102, 111, 111, 100]
```

Then the bits of those bytes are separated into 6-bit groups:

```
[102, 111, 111, 100].map {|b| sprintf('%08b', b) }
=> ["01100110", "01101111", "01101111", "01100100"]

_.join.scan /.{1,6}/
=> ["011001", "100110", "111101", "101111", "011001", "00"]

_.map {|g| g.to_i(2) }
=> [25, 38, 61, 47, 25, 0]
```

These are the numbers you would look up in the table to get the base64-encoded letters. In other words: the `f` in `food` and the `f` in the table are unrelated.

With that out of the way: base64 is used to convert arbitrary bytes to text for situations when text is what’s required. You probably don’t need to base64-encode any *braces*, because HTTP can handle arbitrary bytes in request and response bodies just fine; you will, however, run into trouble trying to JSON-encode arbitrary bytes in Ruby. This is where base64 encoding comes in handy – you can encode the *values* of `payload` before serializing it.

```
encoded_payload = {
    sensitive_information: Base64.encode64(payload[:sensitive_information]),
    iv: Base64.encode64(payload[:iv]),
}
```

Now `JSON.dump` will work fine.

Comment: what are the bytes exactly? Why does f correspond to 102?

Comment: what do you mean by arbitrary bytes?

Comment: @Jwan622: Look at the value of the lowercase `f` in this table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set. “Arbitrary bytes” here means “bytes that may not be UTF-8, and almost certainly aren’t because encrypted data looks like random bytes and IVs are random bytes too”.

Comment: Why does utf 8 encoding convert f to Ascii? Everything else makes sense

Comment: @Jwan622: UTF-8 is backwards-compatible with ASCII, so the table is the same for lowercase `f`.

Comment: last question.... if I'm transmitting the data over ajax requests, (which is http right?)... you're saying I need to encode it somehow (via hexadecimal or ascii or base64) because it'd have trouble json encoding the binary right? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Jwan622: The HTTP part isn’t that important. If you want to send your data as JSON, you will need to use hex or base64 encoding on your two bytestrings (IV and encrypted data) before JSON-encoding, yes.

Comment: Why is that? I guess the obvious fact is that JSON encoding requires everything be a readable character?

Comment: @Jwan622: JSON has no binary data type. It has objects, arrays, numbers, booleans, `null`, and text strings. The best representation for binary data in JSON is a text string, so you need to convert your binary to text. There are many ways to do this (and not all of them include "readable" characters), but base64 is common and straightforward.